# How to automatically prove simple equality of real numbers in Coq?

Tags: coq, coq-tactic, real-number

What I am looking for is an `auto`-like tactic that can prove simple equalities like:

```
1/2 = 2/4
```

So far, what I've tried manually is to use `ring_simplify` and `field_simplify` to prove equalities. Even this doesn't work out well (Coq 8.5b3). The example below works:

```
Require Export Coq.Reals.RIneq.
Local Open Scope Z_scope.
Local Open Scope R_scope.

Example test2: 1 = 1 / 1.
Proof. field_simplify. field_simplify. reflexivity.
Qed.
```

But it was necessary to use `field_simplfy` **twice** before `reflexivity`. The first `field_simplfiy` gives me:

```
1 subgoal
______________________________________(1/1)
1 / 1 = 1 / 1 / (1 / 1)
```

which is not subject to reflexivity.

The example below does not work, `field_simplify` seems to do nothing on the goal, and therefore, `reflexivity` can't be used.

```
Example test3: 1/2 = 2/4.
Proof. field_simplify. reflexivity.
```

Again, is there an automatic way to achieve this, like an `field_auto`?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I believe that tactic `field` is what you want.

```
Require Export Coq.Reals.RIneq.
Local Open Scope Z_scope.
Local Open Scope R_scope.


Example test3: 1/2 = 2/4.
Proof.  field. Qed.
```