# How to auto prove simple inequality of real numbers in Coq?

Tags: automation, coq, inequality, real-number

Is there a way to automatically prove simple inequalities like `1/2 >= 0`?, i.e.

```
Require Export Coq.Reals.RIneq.
Local Open Scope Z_scope.
Local Open Scope R_scope.

Example test: /2 >= 0.
```

I haven't much experience with `ring` or `field`, and [I am having trouble with even proving simple equalities such as `1/2 = 2/4`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34387573/how-to-automatically-prove-simple-equality-of-real-numbers-in-coq).

What I am looking for is something like `omega` but works for real numbers and inequalities.

Comment: @Johan, I rolled back the tag change from real-number to floating-point because I intended ask about the real real numbers, not their floating-point approximations.

Comment: The problem is that real-number only has 7 hits on it, so I think you'd better look for a tag that is in regular use. I'm sure there is a synonym that covers what you want.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The tools you are looking for are described in [the chapter on Omega](https://coq.inria.fr/refman/Reference-Manual024.html) of the reference manual and deal with various arithmetic goals over ordered rings: (non)-linear integer arithmetic, and linear rational / real arithmetic.

They are defined in the `Psatz` module and may require you to install some external solvers. In this case, `lra` does not (AFAICT) have external dependencies and discharges the `test` goal.