# Coq prove that arithmetic expressions involving real number literals are equal

Tags: coq

I have a pretty basic expression involving real number literals and `+`, namely the fact that `4 = 1 + 1 + 1 + 1`.

I'm trying to figure out how to prove this fact using as little cleverness as possible.

```
Require Export RIneq. (* probably overkill, but it pulls in
                         enough real number stuff to be useful *)

Open Scope R_scope.

Lemma test_sum2 : 4 = 1 + 1 + 1 + 1.
```

I attempted to prove it by using strategically chosen assertions and spamming `intuition`, but I can't seem to build integral reals above `3` using that technique.

```
Require Export RIneq.

Open Scope R_scope.

Lemma test_sum2 : 4 = 1 + 1 + 1 + 1.
Proof.
assert (1 + 1 = 2).
intuition.
rewrite H.
assert (1 + 2 = 3).
intuition.
assert (1 + 2 = 2 + 1).
intuition.
rewrite H1 in H0.
rewrite H0.
assert (1 + 3 = 3 + 1).
intuition.
```

leaves me in the proof state

```
1 subgoal
H : 1 + 1 = 2
H0 : 2 + 1 = 3
H1 : 1 + 2 = 2 + 1
H2 : 1 + 3 = 3 + 1
______________________________________(1/1)
4 = 3 + 1
```

Comment: Fun fact: `4%R = IZR (4%Z)`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Based on [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/34387907/4639273) answer, it looks like the `field` tactic will work. I'm not sure if that's too much cleverness.

```
Require Export RIneq.

Open Scope R_scope.

Lemma test_sum2 : 4 = 1 + 1 + 1 + 1.
Proof.
  field.
Qed.
```

(Tested in Coq 8.9+beta1)

Comment: Why not use the more generic `Require Import Reals.`  This gives all the general tools to result about numeric expressions.  For an equality between expression (not necessarily linear), the right answer should be `ring` which is slightly simpler than `field`.  It is worthwhile learning about this tactic, because it is very predictable: *it solves any equality that is true modulo associativity, commutativity, cancellation, of addition, multiplication, subtraction*.

Comment: The tactic `field` proposed here is slightly more powerful than `ring` as it also deals with *division*, but this is trickier because it needs to check that denominators are not zero.